# getElementsByClassName().classList.remove() returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a Marketo form which I want upon form submission to hide all form elements and show a div (class of "thank-you"), and I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined`. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld7fajmy/

HTML

```
<div class="thank-you hide">
  message
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you").classList.remove("hide");
```

Comment: The result of `getElementsByClassName` isn't a single dom node, so I don't think it would have a `classList` property. Are you trying to remove the class from all of them, or just one of them?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you")[0].classList.remove("hide");

Comment: @A. Meshu thanks that worked!

Comment: you welcome! enjoy code (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName` method returns a ***collection of all elements*** in the document with the specified class name, as a **NodeList** object, so you need access it by passing index

```
document.getElementsByClassName("thank-you")[0].classList.remove("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with:

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('message')[0].classList.remove('hide');
```

notice that I removed the . (dot) on "message" - you are getting classNames, so no need to add a dot unless you are using [querySelector](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp).

Also as @tyler mentioned, getElementsByClassName returns a collection of all elements, this will return an array. so you need to add `[0]` to get the first result.